# React - Updating State of Component 2 within Component 1 function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to react and having some trouble.

I have a Main component that represents my entire web app UI. My Main component renders an Info Panel component which displays information. In particular it displays a "player count" which I want to update every time a web socket receives a specific server event.

So the conceptual question: How do I create a functionality for updating the state of a component - with code existing OUTSIDE of the component's class definition? I've read some tutorials and they don't seem to address this exactly, for example, I can send in an onClick prop, but that would allow me to do the reverse - changing component 1 from component 2. I want to change component 2 from component 1, or in fact, anywhere else.

Some workarounds I tried that didn't work:

```
var componentInstance = <SampleComponent />;
componentInstance.setState({
  something: newValue
});
```

I get the error 'componentInstance.setState is not a function' - I'm assuming because setState is private. Why? Is this some kind of design trap?

Then I tried to make a static method to update state to a parameter

```
static updateState(newState) {
  this.setState(newState);
}

socket.on('event', data => {
    sampleComponent.updateState(data);
});
```

Which leads to 'this.setState is not a function' again.

How am I supposed to accomplish this? Isn't this a pretty common desired functionality? Why is it made so difficult?

Comment: "How do I create a functionality for updating the state of a component - with code existing OUTSIDE of the component's class definition?" This is almost certainly the wrong way to go about solving whatever problem you're probably facing. See [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you have a child component that should rerender a count that the parent keeps state on, pass the count into the child's props.

Comment: Are you saying parent components should track all child states inside its own state?

Comment: You do explain your broader problem, but only in a vague way that I can't answer in any meaningful way other than to say what I wrote above. If you want a full answer, please show code and describe the problem agnostic to the solution in a way that's answerable, then describe your attempt. The issue is your question is about Y, not X.

Comment: It takes a while to refactor code for codepen, plus, my code uses web sockets and depends on a locally hosted server, so I hoped to get a conceptual answer.

Comment: They aren't parent-child. It's simply that inside component1.render(), <component2 /> is used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220459/discussion-between-zingzing45-and-ggorlen).